# Tag cloud with text field in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new to Elastic and Kibana. I'm creating my first visualizations in Kibana. 
I have a index with news with the following fields:

- News title (text)
- News body (text): the text of the article
  [image]
- Top 5 keywords (list of keywords). It contains the top 5 keywords of the body

I created a tag cloud with the "top 5 keywords" field. I'd like to do the same with the "body". However, I don't see the field  available when creating the visualization:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of my mapping: 
[image]

I assume there's something wrong with my mapping but I cannot figure that out.
any help?!
Many thanks!
Raul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each visualization is a kind of aggregation.

`text` [type not allow aggregations by default. This is to keep the heap memory amount](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#fielddata-disabled-text-fields).

[before you enable `fielddata` on the body be sure that you know what you do](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#before-enabling-fielddata)

For enable, `fielddata` on body field add to your mapping

```
{
  "properties": {
    "body": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

[documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#enable-fielddata-text-fields)

Comment: thanks! after reading those references I realised I better don't do it that way: "Before you enable fielddata, consider why you are using a text field for aggregations, sorting, or in a script. It usually doesn’t make sense to do so."
I just increased my top words field to top10 instead of 5 and I will use that on my tag cloud.

Comment: You welcome. I mеt number people that have serious problems according wrong using fielddata. Good like.